# Poner valor por defecto en SELECT de vista

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy creando una vista donde almacenar todos los usuarios, pero en una tabla no tengo el rol asignado. Me gustaría ponerle 5.

Así es como creo la vista:

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `users` AS
SELECT 
    `usuarios`.`id` AS `id`,
    `usuarios`.`usuario` AS `username`,
    `usuarios`.`password` AS `password`,
    `usuarios`.`role_id` AS `role`
FROM
    `usuarios` 
UNION SELECT 
    `personas`.`id` AS `id`,
    `personas`.`username` AS `username`,
    `personas`.`password` AS `password`,
    `personas`.`id`  AS `role`
FROM
    `personas`
```

Pero mi intencion es hacer algo así

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `users` AS
SELECT 
    `usuarios`.`id` AS `id`,
    `usuarios`.`usuario` AS `username`,
    `usuarios`.`password` AS `password`,
    `usuarios`.`role_id` AS `role`
FROM
    `usuarios` 
UNION SELECT 
    `personas`.`id` AS `id`,
    `personas`.`username` AS `username`,
    `personas`.`password` AS `password`,
    `5`  AS `role`
FROM
    `personas`
```

Me da error porque no existe la columna `5` y en el primer caso, en el role, le estoy asignado la `id`, porque necesito tener las mismas columnas pero hay quiero introducir un `5` pero no sé cómo conseguirlo.

Comment: ¿Y no puedes crear la columna rol en la tabla personas y que tenga el valor por defecto 5?
alter table personas add rol int not null default 5

Comment: No porque la tabla personas la obtengo de otro lugar y viene con esos datos.

Comment: Donde pones `\`5\`` haces referencia al campo `5`, por eso se usan comillas invertidas, para diferenciar literales, funciones o cadenas de un nombre de tabla o campo. Si quieres que sea un número 5 debes quitarle las comillas invertidas (`5` a secas).

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo consegui de esta manera aunque no se si realmente esta bien lo que hago.

```
CREATE 
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `users` AS
SELECT 
    `usuarios`.`id` AS `id`,
    `usuarios`.`usuario` AS `username`,
    `usuarios`.`password` AS `password`,
    `usuarios`.`role_id` AS `role`
FROM
    `usuarios` 
UNION SELECT 
    `personas`.`id` AS `id`,
    `personas`.`username` AS `username`,
    `personas`.`password` AS `password`,
    IFNULL(NULL, 5) AS `role`
FROM
    `personas`
```

Comment: Mira mi respuesta porque con esta consulta tendrás campos duplicados.

Answer (score 0):

Donde pones `` `5` `` haces referencia al campo cuyo nombre es `5`, para eso se usan comillas invertidas, para diferenciar literales, funciones o cadenas del nombre de tabla o campo. Si quieres que sea un número 5 debes quitarle las comillas invertidas (`5` a secas).

Además, si lo que quieres es que te ponga un `5` en aquellos campos donde no esté ese rol porque sea `NULL`, entonces puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
CREATE
ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW users AS
SELECT
    id,
    usuario username,
    password,
    IF(ISNULL(role_id), 5, role_id) role
FROM
    usuarios
```

He usado un condicional [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) para comprobar si el campo es nulo o no con [`ISNULL()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull). En caso de ser nulo devuelvo el número `5`, y en caso de que no lo sea devuelvo el valor del campo.